# error while parsing an jsonarray

Tags: android, json, json-rpc

I am making a webservice call and the respond is in JSON.
The content which i get, is a JSONArray and looks like this:

> {"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":"req-002","result":[
>                       {"id":125043,"date":20110117,"startTime":800,"endTime":850,
>                       "kl":[{"id":71}],"te":[{"id":23}],"su":[{"id":13}],"ro":[{"id":1}]},
>                       {"id":125127,"date":20110117,"startTime":1055,"endTime":1145,
>                       "kl":[{"id":71}],"te":[{"id":41}],"su":[{"id":19}],"ro":[{"id":31}]},
>                       ]}

Now i am trying to get the objects in the array, but i am only able to fetch the first array: for example i cant get the first "kl" array but i am not able to get the second one.
It always give me the error :

> org.json.JSONException: Index 1 out of range [0..1)

This is what i have tried:

```
 JSONObject jsonResult = new JSONObject(s);
            // Get the result object
            JSONArray arr = jsonResult.getJSONArray("result");
            Log.d("Arraylänge", String.valueOf(arr.length()));

            for(int i=0; i<arr.length(); i++){
                JSONObject c = arr.getJSONObject(i);

                anfangStunde[i] = c.getString("startTime");
                endeStunde[i] = c.getString("endTime");

                JSONArray klArr = c.getJSONArray("kl");
                for(int j=0; i<klArr.length(); j++)
                {
                    JSONObject k =  klArr.getJSONObject(j);
                    klassenID[j] = k.getString("id");
                }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo `for(int j=0; **i**<klArr.length(); j++)`